# TableAdapter update SQL server CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, strongly-typed-dataset

I am trying to update my SQL Server CE database after commiting changes to a typed dataset. The changes are all in the table but won't update to the database. Thank you in advance!

```
static MoviesTableAdapter adapter;
static MovieDataSet dataset;
static MovieDataSet.MoviesDataTable table;

adapter = new MoviesTableAdapter();
dataset = new MovieDataSet();
table = adapter.GetData(); 

MovieDataSet.MoviesRow row = table.NewMoviesRow();
row.example = example....
table.AddMoviesRow(row);

adapter.Update(table);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're checking the database located at your /bin/debug folder?

Comment: Oops. Stupid to not think about that, thanks! You may post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens a lot with SQL Server CE, or Access, or any other file based database. You have a copy of the database on the solution folder, and it's copied to /bin/debug everytime you run your solution: that's the version you gotta check to see if your changes are persisted.